# form onsubmit ignores action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to JavaScript. I have a form with an action and I need to fill the form inputs using JavaScript on submitting. I use an `onsubmit` function which executes as expected, but the form didn't hit the action in the `action` attribute and no data is sent to the server.
Can anybody help me find what is missing ?

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return fillFormValues();
})

function fillFormValues()
{
  $.get( ...,function( data ) {
    //fill my inputs values here
    return true;
  });
  return false;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="..." method="post" target="output_frame" id="myForm">
    <input name="first" id="first" type="hidden" value="">
    ...
    <input type="submit"  value="next">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post your `server-side` code on where you will send the data to the server?

Comment: I send it to a gateway url its not mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you can do is prevent the jQuery event default that would submit the form, do the ajax and once values are set trigger  the native submit event that will bypass the jQuery submit listener

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  fillFormValues(this);
});

function fillFormValues(form) {
  $.get(..., function(data) {
    //fill your inputs values here
    form.submit(); //trigger native submit which is not caught by jQuery
  });
}
```

Comment: FYI another way is set a flag variable for `updated` and submit the jquery again but immediately return true so it doesn't get into infinite loop